# Matching characters reversely using regex

Tags: regex, delphi

i need a regex that matches a string from specified position to first character reversely. strings are some file names.

- i m using Delphi 2010
- my example string is New Document.extension
- if specified position is 4, it should match:
  New Docu

You can get from "New Document.extension" to "New docu" following those steps:

- First strip the extension. You end up with "New Document"
- Remove the last 4 characters. You get "New Docu".

For the "This Is My Longest Document.ext1.ext2" example:

- Strip the extension, you end up with: "This Is My Longest Document.ext1"
- Strip the last 4 characters. You get: "This Is My Longest Document."

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Please improve question.

Comment: I do not understand how you got from "New Document.extension" to "New Docu". Please explain your transformation using plain English.

Comment: thanks for the replies. if the string is "New Document.txt" or "New Document.jpg" or any other extension, it should match "New Docu" (if the specified position is 4). sorry for my English.

Comment: <psychic powers>I think he means repeatedly instead of reversely. From the example he seams to need the specified number of character from every word in the filename (excluding the extension)...</psychic powers>

Comment: @onur, to check Marjan's psychic powers, what would you get from "This Is My Longest Document.ext1.ext2"?

Comment: if you mean example string is "This Is My Longest Document.ext1.ext2" i say it should match "This Is My Longest Document." because there's one extension: ext2

Comment: i accidently pressed enter. "string.ext" has 6 characters except for the extension. its 4th letter from last letter is "r", if we count reversely. so the regex should match "st".

Comment: "string.ext" has 6 characters except for the extension. its 4th letter is "r", while we are counting reversely from the last letter. so the regex should match "st".

Comment: I think I understand this less now than before the comments were added.

Comment: Well I guess my psychic powers were not up to par today :-))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want the entire string up to the fourth-to-last position before the final dot? No problem:

Delphi .NET:

```
ResultString := Regex.Match(SubjectString, '^.*(?=.{4}\.[^.]*$)').Value;
```

**Explanation:**

```
^       # Start of string
.*      # Match any number of characters
(?=     # Assert that it's possible to match, starting at the current position:
 .{4}   # four characters
 \.     # a dot (the last dot in the string!) because...
 [^.]*  # from here one only non-dots are allowed until...
 $      # the end of the string.
)       # End of lookahead.
```

Comment: Unless using the regex is a requirement for some reason, I'd suggest using a procedural approach since relying on regex lookaheads is going to be inefficient.

Comment: @Cosmin: When using regexes, I never feel fully confident I'll catch all occurrences. That's no big problem for manual manipulation of a text, but I'd hate to use it in code. <g>

Answer (score 4):

Since I can't post the regex because I came up with the exact same Regex as Tim, I'm going to post a piece of procedural code that does the exact same thing.

```
function FileNameWithoutExtension(const FileName:string; const StripExtraNumChars: Integer): string;
var i: Integer;
begin
  i := LastDelimiter('.', FileName); // The extension starts at the last dot
  if i = 0 then i := Length(FileName) + 1; // Make up the extension position if the file has no extension
  Dec(i, StripExtraNumChars + 1); // Strip the requested number of chars; Plus one for the dot itself
  Result := Copy(FileName, 1, i); // This is the result!
end;
```

Comment: Not bad. :) Quicker: `Result := ChangeFileExt(FileName, ''); Result := Copy(Result, 1, Length(Result) - NumCharsToRemove);`

Comment: Doing it in two steps re-allocates the string twice.

Comment: Ummm... So? :) We're talking about short allocations here, and there's a lot less overhead (and memory use) than the original regex request would use. Conciseness and maintainability to me is typically more important, unless there's some actual reason to worry about really small allocations of memory.

Comment: @Ken I think once we've stopped using the regex, then we are haggling over small change!  ;-)

Comment: @David: I agree, as I mentioned to Cosmin. :) I actually upvoted his answer, and gave an alternative solution to his in a comment rather than a separate answer intentionally, not wanting votes for it that he might get.

Comment: @Ken Or votes that I might get ;-) Did you notice the similarity between your comment and my answer?!!

Comment: @David - not when I posted my comment to Cosmin's post. :) I can't tell exactly what the timing was between my comment and your answer, so I don't know which actually came first (if either - they may have been at the same time).

Comment: @Ken Hover over the time next to the comment/answer and the precise time stamp comes up. My answer was 20 minutes before your comment in fact. Funny that the code is identical! I hadn't seen Cosmin's answer when I did mine, mind you, even though it's 10 minutes before mine.

Comment: @Ken, don't read too much in my comment... your answer starts with `"Not bad. Quicker:"` well, your method is not quicker; But it does use half the lines of code and it is easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

You accepted the answer giving a regex for

> The entire string up to the fourth-to-last position before the final dot.

If that's what you want then you do it best without a regex:

```
procedure RemoveExtensionAndFinalNcharacters(var s: string; N: Integer);
begin
  s := ChangeFileExt(s, '');//remove extension
  s := Copy(s, 1, Length(s)-N);//remove final N characters
end;
```

This more efficient than a regex and, much more importantly, it is much clearer and more intelligible.

Regexes are not the only fruit.

Comment: +1. I wouldn't have used a procedure, though. I prefer functions with return values rather than var params when possible.

Comment: @Ken I do too, I just couldn't think of a good name that was a noun since it's such an odd thing to do. Easy to name with a verb!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit based on comments**

I'm not sure how Delphi does regex, but this works in most systems.

```
^.*(?=.{4}\.\w+$)

^                #the start of the string
.*               #Any characters.
(?=              #A lookahead meaning followed by...
.{4}             #Any 4 chars.
\.               #A literal .
\w+              #an actual extension.
$                #the end of the string
)                #closing the lookahead
```

You could also use `\w{3}$` instead of `\w+` at the end if you wanted to make sure that the extension was three charaters long.

Comment: How did you test your regex? When subjected to the text "New Document.extension" it only matches "Docu".

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. but i couldn't modify it to remove word restriction. what i need is get all characters to the beginning. when i test the code it matches "Docu". i need it to match "New Docu" (while the string is "New Document.ext")

Comment: @onur, sorry. I just fixed that. let me know if this one has problems.